# Django REST - PATCH for replacing nested object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to replace one tested object another using PATCH request. For My experiments I use Postman. I send PATCH request with parameter user_status and value:

> {"id": 1, "status_type": {"id": 2, "name": "new_status_type_name"},
>   "name": "new_status_name"}

I wrote update method for updating my ResultSerializer, but it doesn't work. Now I'm debuging it and I see that variable validated_data doesn't contain my new user_status. user_status is an empty OrderedDict:

```
ipdb> validated_data['user_status']
OrderedDict()
```

I checked my request and I see that user_status is a list with one element - string.

```
ipdb> self.context['request'].data
<QueryDict: {'user_status': ['{"id": 1, "status_type": {"id": 2, "name": "new_status_type_name"}, "name": "new_status_name"}']}>
```

How can I replace one another nested objects? Thank you for your help.

I have next Models:

```
class UserStatus(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    status_type = models.ForeignKey('StatusType', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user_status'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class StatusType(models.Model):
    id = models.SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=256)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'status_type'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Result(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user_status = models.ForeignKey('UserStatus', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'result'
```

Serializers:

```
class UserStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField()
    status_type = StatusTypeSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = app.models.UserStatus


class StatusTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = app.models.StatusType


class ResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_status = UserStatusSerializer(many=False)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data, *args, **kwargs):
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        instance.user_status = validated_data.get('user_status', instance.user_status)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = app.models.Result
```

Views:

```
class StatusTypeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = app.models.StatusType.objects.all()
    serializer_class = app.serializers.StatusTypeSerializer


class UserStatusViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = app.models.UserStatus.objects.all()
    serializer_class = app.serializers.UserStatusSerializer


class ResultViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = app.models.Result.objects.all()
    serializer_class = app.serializers.ResultSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading of this article [Please. Don't Patch Like An Idiot.](http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/)
I understood that I should use the list for patching, but Django REST doesn't want to use list, only objects. Ok, now I use next dict for pathcing:

```
{"op": "update", "field": "user_status_id", "new_value": 2}
```

and next code for sending this list:

```
import json
import requests

payload = json.dumps({"op": "update", "field": "user_status_id", "new_value": 2})
headers = {'content-type': "application/json"}
response = requests.patch(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Then I changed serializers.py and views.py. I'll show you only main code without checking and other stufs :).
views.py (added the method [perform_update](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods)):

```
class ResultViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = app.models.Result.objects.all()
    serializer_class = app.serializers.ResultSerializer

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        new_value = self.request.data.get('new_value')
        user_status_ins = app.models.UserStatus.objects.get(id=new_value)
        serializer.save(user_status=user_status_ins)
```

serializers.py (added the method [update](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances)):

```
class ResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_status = UserStatusSerializer(many=False)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data, *args, **kwargs):
        for field in validated_data.keys():
            setattr(instance, field, validated_data.get(field))
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = app.models.Result
```

If you found better solution, please tell me.